# haystack startswith includes first letter from subsequent words

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I am a little baffled with the `startswith` filter from the `SearchQuerySet`. I am the following index:

```
class PropertyProjectIndex(indexes.SearchIndex):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    project_district_num  = indexes.CharField(model_attr='project_district_num', null=True)
    property_type = indexes.CharField(model_attr='property_type', null=True)
    project_title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='project_title', null=True) 

    def get_model(self):
        return PropertyProject
```

When I run the query

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(PropertyProject).filter(project_title__startswith='S')
```

I have results like `PALM SPRING` and `RISING SUITES`. It seems like the first letter of the subsequent words were also taken into account. When I read the docs for django, the `__startswith=S` translates into `where attribute like 'S%'` in SQL. Is this not the same for `SearchQuerySet`?